# How to customize theme in Material-UI with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I tried to change defaults of `MuiContainer` by this way:

```js
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiContainer: {
            maxWidthLg: 1400,
        }
    }
})
```

And then received type error:
`Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | CreateCSSProperties<{}>` 
What should I do to be able to customize `maxWidthLg` property of `MuiContainer`?

Comment: `maxWidthLg` expects styling but you are providing a number. What do you want to customize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good that you found the answer!
For anybody else when you face such a problem with Material-UI and you are using and IDE that will let you jump to the file responsible in node_modules (or you can search for it) With a little reading you might solve it and maybe get a better understanding of the thing you are trying to use ex:

```js
export interface TransitionsOptions {
  easing?: Partial<Easing>;
  duration?: Partial<Duration>;
  create?: (
    props: string | string[],
    options?: Partial<{ duration: number | string; easing: string; delay: number | string }>
  ) => string;
  getAutoHeightDuration?: (height: number) => number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer, folks
As [isAif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4901118/isaif) answered in comments, object has to be specified instead of number. 
I wanted to customize `maxWidth` of class `MuiContainer-maxWidthLg`, so instead of doing this:

```js
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiContainer: {
            maxWidthLg: 1400,
        }
    }
})
```

I need to do this:

```js
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiContainer: {
            maxWidthLg: {
                maxWidth: 1400
            }
        }
    }
})
```